# Details of a 301 Redirect

Tags: php, http, redirect

I'm doing an assignment with PHP and I've implemented a 301 redirect if the URL is entered with minor errors. This got me thinking about how a redirect actually works. I'm using something fairly basic like this:

`header("Location: https://www.example.com");`

I've also noticed that Apache automatically redirects when directory is entered without a trailing slash. The result is the same.

My understanding is that server sends response with 301 status and appropriate Location header. Now, does the client need to make another request, or does the server send the correct resource automatically? Also, can the client ignore the redirect?

Comment: The client makes another request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a redirect is returned, the client makes another request to the new URL. The redirect could be to an entirely different server, so the original server couldn't send the correct resource by itself. And even if the server could return the resource by itself, the client needs to know about the new URL, because relative URLs within it need to be resolved relative to that location, not the original location.

Clients can certainly ignore the redirect. The `curl` client only follows redirects if you use the `--location` option. Most clients also have a limit on the number of redirects they'll follow to satisfy a single request, to prevent redirect loops.

Comment: Redirect loop was easy to demonstrate by setting Location header to point to the PHP script invoking header(). Looks a lot like infinite recursion.